# How to be sure to update a unique MySql row without a unique ID

Tags: mysql

I have this problem:

1. I show a table to a user. I cannot be sure, neither I can force it, that the table contains a unique value anywhere
2. The user changes a SINGLE field value
3. I must be able to update it in the DB, of course in the CORRECT row

Now, if the table had e.g. an id autoincrement/unique field, piece of cake:

```
UPDATE table SET field=value WHERE id=storedId
```

But, as said, I cannot be sure.
I thought about these solutions:

1. I can temporary store ALL the field values, so that I can do the update with WHERE f1=v1 AND f2=v2 AND fn=vn but the problem is that IF THERE ARE multiple rows with THE SAME values, it will update all of them
2. Same as above, with LIMIT 1. Well, if it's the first, it's correct. If it's the second, it's wrong.
3. I can do a SELECT * FROM table, store the position of that particular row, and assuming that NOBODY ELSE touches the DB (fair assumption in my specific case), I can maybe find a way to update only that specific ROW, but I still do not know how (I tried with LIMIT ROW,1 but it doesn't work)

So, yes, I know, in a multi-user, multi-tasking environment I should lock the tables and so on but no, it's just one user, so I do not have to care about it.
But still, I cannot find a solution or even a hack to do what I need :(

PS: I was thinking if within MySql every row has a unique ID anyway that I can retrieve somehow, so I can refer to it

PS2: How can PHPMyAdmin for example let you edit a table without a primary key then?

Comment: Easy. You can't.

Comment: Finding a way to add a primary key is a better use of your time

Comment: I cannot modify the database. I have only r/w access to the records, not to the structure

Comment: About case 1 & case 2: if all values are the same, why using LIMIT 1 first is correct but 2 is wrong? On the other hand, i think you need to talk with DB admin about this.

Comment: Find what's the PK of the DB : if you don't have duplicate row in the Db, then there is probably a PK. Usually mail, full name or real-life ID.

Comment: About solution 2: If you have lets say 10 rows that are completely the same, does it matter which one you update?